# Vue Router - cannot read query params in lazy loaded components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, lazy-loading, vue-router, query-string

I have a lazy loaded components in Vue Router like this:

```
const Login = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "pages" */ "@/views/Pages/Login.vue");
```

But in such loaded components I'm not able to read `this.$route.query`. The object is always empty.

Why? Or how can I get query params in lazy loaded components?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the result of `this.$route` ?

Comment: In `App.vue` in `mounted` I call this: `console.log(this.$route)`. The url is: `http://localhost:8081/#/home?hash=now` Printed object: `fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: null
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}`. The whole object looks weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty late for the party, but still got some tasty cake to share.

The problem is that when a component is lazily initialized, the route object is not avaiable inside the component constructor.

That's how I've just solved the problem.

Component route configuration:

```
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: "/my-comp",
    name: "MyComponent",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "MyComponent" */ "../views/MyComponentView.vue"),
  },
]
```

You have to actually mount the app after the router is **ready** by taking advantage of the **onReady** callback. In my *main.ts*:

```
const vue = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
});

router.onReady(() => {
  vue.$mount("#app");
});
```

And now I can safely access the route's query inside of *MyComponentView.vue* constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.$route.query.selectedItem; // correctly initialized
}
```